# Is it possible to make CStr throw an exception?

Tags: vb.net

I have some legacy code that looks like this:

```
Try
    Dim val As String = CStr(some_other_value)
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Do exception stuff here
End Try
```

I'm curious; is it even possible for `CStr` to throw an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that to error if the thing being cast is not capable of being cast as a string.

Example:

```
Dim a as New Object
Dim s As String
s = CStr(a)
```

This causes

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from type 'Object' to type
>   'String' is not valid.'

I'm having trouble finding any other cases which can cause it as most other cases cause a compile time error.

Comment: This could be the only possible exception, as the max size of a String is 1073741824 chars but that would cause an OutOfMemoryException outside the `CStr()`

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions):

> ***Behavior***
>
> - **Failed Conversions**. If the expression passed to the function is outside the range of the data type to which it is to be converted, an
>     [OverflowException](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) occurs.

Comment: Yes, I also read that. But that prompts the second question in relation to `CStr` specifically: how do you make a string overflow?

Comment: @Woody1193 I saw some OverflowException referring to a String, but this will happen if the string is created programmatically and there is some bug/errors in that part of the code

Comment: But it is nearly impossible to happens because the max size of an obj in visual studio is 2GB

Answer (score 1):

You could get an exception from `CStr()` if the object's string conversion were to throw an exception.  A trivial example would be:

```
Class MyObject
    Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal o As MyObject) As String
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Operator
End Class
```

Calling `CStr()` on an instance of `MyObject` will throw.  Obviously, this is only potentially an issue with object types.